# Send-MailMessage Access to path is denied

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send files by email using powershell. I am able to pop up a prompt for password for credential to run. But the send-mailmessage come back saying the path is denied. Also is there a way to include the password in the script to bypass entering the password so that I can run this through task scheduler on the server?

```
Send-MailMessage -From 'David Brierton <Davidb@test.com>' -To 'David Brierton <Davidb@test.com>' -Subject "Website deployment" -Body "See attached file" -Attachments @("\\server\d$\Mdrive\test\test\Book1.csv", "\\server\d$\Mdrive\test\test\ExampleBook1.csv") -SmtpServer test.test.test -Credential DomainName\User
```

Comment: It looks like the error is occurring when accessing the files, does the error occur when you omit them?

Comment: If I delete the attachment and run it there are no errors but I still do not receive the email.

Comment: Not receiving the email would be a different problem, let work through them one at a time. To fix the issue at hand you need to be sure the account accessing the files from the share will have the permissions required to do so. How are you running the script?

Comment: the goal is to run it through task scheduler on a server

Comment: does the server have to have outlook on it?

Comment: Outlook is not needed, the cmdlet has all the features needed to send an email. If you are running the task as a user the user must have access to the files on the share if you are running the task with "highest privileges" the computer the task runs on must have permissions.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this the email is not coming through. Its not erroring out so I am unsure how to check this out now

Comment: You'll need to check your mail server to see why that is happening.

Comment: Do you have a valid SMTP server?

Comment: Check the logs of your SMTP server, or start tracing the path of the incoming request and see at what point your code stops. If you are getting a silent error, or none of the expected behaviours, then chances are an error is being swallowed and it appears that nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the @ and the bracket in the -attachement and try with only your email

```
Send-MailMessage -From "Davidb@test.com" -To "Davidb@test.com" -Subject "Website deployment" -Body "See attached file" -Attachments "\\server\d$\Mdrive\test\test\Book1.csv", "\\server\d$\Mdrive\test\test\ExampleBook1.csv" -SmtpServer test.test.test -Credential DomainName\User
```

Comment: I tried this there were no errors but never received the emails

Comment: You should focus on the SMTP server then. i ran a script like this and it's working fine

Comment: Do you know what I would check in the SMTP?

Comment: Do you have a valid smtp server ?  did you tried to use the ip of the server instead of the hostname ?

Comment: Yes we have a valid ip but then i get an access to path is denied